# How to open an opened file in C

Tags: c, linux, file

I have a program which opens /dev/watchdog file. I want this kind of program to get the access of file with force. I mean the main program was running and was using this file, another instance of program was able to open the /dev/watchdog by force and write to it.

I have searched about tags which exists in open function

Comment: Unix doesn't have any way to prevent multiple files from opening the same file. If you want to coordinate which process can use the file, you need to use locks.

Comment: Coming from a mainframe environment, I find this fact quite shocking. You can identify which process is using the file with lsof | grep /dev/watchdog or just lsof -R /dev/watchdog and then kill it, but this is a dangerous thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to the community!

UNIX does not have a way to prevent any number of processes from using the same file, on its own. What you're trying to achieve can be done by using a [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) in the shape of locks. The system call [flock](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) allows you to apply and remove locks on an already open file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rithari
By using flock I have control of closing and opening files from multiple processes?

Comment: @AlirezaMortezaei by using file locks you have the power of exclusivity over a certain file. You are able to prevent any other process to access the file until you unlock it again. Do note though that `flock` only places an **advisory** lock on the file, which means that given sufficient permissions, one may still access the file.